# Formula to get "Date" based on Activity History Subject

Tags: formula, custom-field, datetime

Since Activity History combines everything such as Calls, Marketo, Email, Etc. In CONTACTS.  I am looking for a formula that will get the last activity date based on the subject that **contains "Email"**  that will show on my custom object.

scenario:
If John Doe has over 100 activity history and the last 10 activities he has is all calls but the 11th activity is email and has email on the subject.  It will get the date of the email activity.

thanks for reading and thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research I  have to use a Process Builder and update record in the related task. Now in the contact section, have the process builder call the flow to query the contact and set the last activity date.